# Purpose of jar files refereed in the book "Hadoop" by Tom White, 4th Edition?

Tags: maven, hadoop, jar

I downloaded the git repo and made jar files, but unable to find their purpose and how to use them?

Comment: A jar file is like a ZIP file for Java class files. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)).

Answer (score 0):

You can run them via

`hadoop jar <jar file> <className>`

But you need to know the names of the classes ahead of time.

The book has code examples that are all runnable, for the most part